# user's email is always NULL - Spring Social Facebook Login

Tags: spring, facebook, email, facebook-graph-api

According to [Facebook's official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions), email access is given to any app provided user accepts and grants permission when login using Facebook.

I've double checked our app definition and I can see email should be accessible.

[image]

I'm using the latest available from Spring Social

```
<spring-social-security>1.1.4.RELEASE</spring-social-security>
<spring-social-core>1.1.4.RELEASE</spring-social-core>
<spring-social-facebook>2.0.3.RELEASE</spring-social-facebook>
```

Users successfully login using Facebook as a provider as well as Google+ and Twitter.

Unfortunately for **all cases email is NULL** except for my own user.

There are two scenarios where email could be null though

- if someone signed up for Facebook with a phone number instead of an email address, the email field may be empty
- This field will not be returned if no valid email address is available

I've triple checked that by accessing a friend's of mine account which

1. It's got a valid email verified
2. It's got a phone number associated with it
3. We are friends with each other
4. His phone and email are visible for his friends

I go to the [GraphApi explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) but no email is ever returned.

Any advice? Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @m.aibin    `public String execute(final org.springframework.social.connect.Connection<?> connection) {
        //add new users to the db with its default roles for later use in SocialAuthenticationSuccessHandler
        final org.springframework.social.connect.UserProfile userProfile = connection.fetchUserProfile();
        final String uemail = userProfile.getUsername();
        final String uname = userProfile.getEmail();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found where the problem was. I was not adding the required scopes to the social connection factory.

```
FacebookConnectionFactory fcf = new FacebookConnectionFactory(
            env.getProperty("oauth.facebook.api.key"),
            env.getProperty("oauth.facebook.api.secret"));
   //this is the important bit 
   fcf.setScope("public_profile,email");

   .....
```

**email** was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is that you tries to fetch username. Currently, Facebook got rid of the username because the username is one way of sending emails via Facebook.

You can try to delete this line:

```
final String uemail = userProfile.getUsername();
```

and check if you can get email.
Here is my code that I use to fetch email etc.:

```
OAuth2Operations oauthOperations = fbProvider.getOAuthOperations();
AccessGrant accessGrant = oauthOperations.exchangeForAccess(authorizationCode, facebookCallback, null);
String accessToken = accessGrant.getAccessToken();

Connection<Facebook> connection = fbConnectionFactory.createConnection(accessGrant);

UserProfile profile = connection.fetchUserProfile();
ConnectionKey connectionKey = connection.getKey();
String usn = connectionKey.getProviderUserId();
String email = profile.getEmail();
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the fact I was assigning username to email variable and email to username variable. Exactly inverted! Having said that, I still don't see what's different between your code and mine. Ultimately you get the email from UserProfile which is instantiated in the same way I do by doing `UserProfile profile = connection.fetchUserProfile();`  I'm testing it now anyway...

Comment: No luck. Email is null always. Strangely I could not retrieve any of my friends email from GraphAPI browser even though my friend's got a verified account and he's got set in privacy that email is visible to friends. It means I should get access to it but I couldn't from GraphAPI browser. I can see it from UI but no way otherwise. Have you checked your code effectively retrieves emails for other users than your own?

Answer (score 0):

As @felipe mentioned, it required to set permission/scope to get email during facebook login in spring social.

If you are using XML format instead of java class for config then you can be defined scope as follow.

```
 <bean id="connectionFactoryRegistry"
              class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationServiceRegistry">
            <property name="authenticationServices">
                <util:list>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.social.facebook.security.FacebookAuthenticationService">
                        <constructor-arg value="${facebook.clientId}"/>
                        <constructor-arg value="${facebook.clientSecret}"/>
                        <property name="defaultScope" value="email"/>
                    </bean>
                </util:list>
            </property>
        </bean>
        <alias name="connectionFactoryRegistry" alias="connectionFactoryLocator"/>
```

I spent a few hours to find a way to set'scope' via XML config. so posting solution here that can be helpful to others.

Ref:-https://github.com/timeu/GWA-Portal/blob/c4fffb0cc4aeb295d9eef7c642c7a25090560014/genophenbrowser-server/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring-social.xml